# Visualizing multiheadattention activation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've trained a model for a segmentation problem where my data is completely numerical. The input shape is (batch, 200, 5), where 200 are the timesteps and 5 the features I'm using, the output prediction shape is (batch, 200, 2), where 200 is the timesteps and 2 is a one-hot encoding of two classes. To improve training I used a tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention layer so it focuses on the features and timesteps that are more relevant to the problem. Now I want to visualize which features and timesteps of my data are most relevant but I'm not sure how to approach it and if what I'm currently doing is correct.

What I'm currently doing is using [keract](https://github.com/philipperemy/keract) library to get the activations of my model for a given input, then I'm getting the activation of the "multi_head_attention" layer and I'm plotting it. The code for that look as the following:

```
import keract
multi_head_attention_activation = keract.get_activations(model, xtrain[0:1], auto_compile=True)['multi_head_attention']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 15))
ax.set_xticklabels(['attr1',"attr2", "attr3", "att4", "attr5"], rotation=90, minor=False)
pos = ax.imshow(mean_activation, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar(pos)
```

To which the plot looks like this:

[image]

This kind of visualization does make sense to me, but when I look at the documentation for the attention layer I see the following code:

```
layer = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=2, key_dim=2)
target = tf.keras.Input(shape=[8, 16])
source = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4, 16])
output_tensor, weights = layer(target, source,
                           return_attention_scores=True)
print(output_tensor.shape)

print(weights.shape)
```

The weights that it returns is probably what I actually want to plot and see, and also which features it sees as most important, but how do I actually get to these values given my data and how do I interpret this?